# JavaCompiler with dependent class

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I'm using JavaCompiler to compile a class. I have jar dependency, where I used to give it in class path, I have a class (class1) file in the same directly, which is a dependent for another class (class2).

Simply

Class1.class
Class2.java

I want to compile Class2.java, in Class2 have a code like

```
Class1.sayHi();
```

When I compile it its saying

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

How can I include Class1.class while compiling Class2

My compiler code

```
String fileToCompile = classFile;
System.setProperty("java.home", RuntimeCompiler.getJDKPath());
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationSource =
     fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(fileToCompile);
List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath",dynamicClassPath));
try{
    compiler.getTask(null, null, null, optionList, null, compilationSource).call();
    return true;
}catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is the file `Class1` in the classpath? Just because the code in that file invokes the compilation doesn't mean it is recognised by the compiler.

Comment: No, how to include a Class1 in classpath? I dont know to include a class file. I gave like the follow

    C:/work/sample1/core/com/ExternalResoruceExcel.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class path for a particular compiled class can be given as

```
-classpath "full_folder_Path_Till_Package"
```

Ex:

```
dynamicClassPath = "C:/work/sample1/core"
```

in core directory you will have package folder "com" inside that dependant class.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple files/classes on the class path.  Just separate them with either a colon or semicolon, depending on your platform.

Have you verified that it will compile using just the javac command?  If this works then it must be something in your procedure and not the class path.

Comment: Can you pls tell how to give reference to Class1.class in classpath?

Comment: When invoking javac you just specify cp=Class1.class